# Does the constant in Poincaré inequality (for $W^{1,p}_0$) depend on $p$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

The classical Poincaré inequality states that

> Let $1 \le p < \infty$ and $U$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists a constant $C$ (depending only on $U$ and $p$) such that for any function $u\in W^{1,p}_0(U)$,
> $$\|u\|_{L^{p}(U)}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^{p}(U)}$$

Let $\Omega=\prod_{i=1}^n[a_i, b_i]$ such that $U\subseteq\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_U |u(x)|^pdx
&\stackrel{(1)}{=} \int_\Omega |u(x)|^pdx \\
&= \int_\Omega \left|\int_{t=a_1}^{x_1} \partial_1u(t,x_2,\dots,x_n)\,dt\right|^pdx \\
&\le \int_\Omega \left(\int_{t=a_1}^{b_1} \left|\partial_1u(t,x_2,\dots,x_n)\right|\,dt\right)^pdx \\
&\le \int_\Omega \left(\int_{t=a_1}^{b_1} \left|\nabla u(t,x_2,\dots,x_n)\right|\,dt\right)^pdx \\
&\stackrel{(2)}{\le} \int_\Omega
\left(\int_{t=a_1}^{b_1} 1\,dt\right)^{p/p'}
\left(\int_{t=a_1}^{b_1} \left|\nabla u(t,x_2,\dots,x_n)\right|^p\,dt\right)
dx \\
&\le (\text{diam}\,\Omega)^{p/p'} \int_\Omega\int_{t=a_1}^{b_1}|\nabla u(t,x_2,\ldots,x_n)|^p\,dtdx \\
&\stackrel{(3)}{\le} (\text{diam}\,\Omega)^{(p/p')+1} \int_\Omega|\nabla u(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)|^p\,dx \\
&\stackrel{(4)}{=} (\text{diam}\,\Omega)^{p} \int_\Omega|\nabla u(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)|^p\,dx
\end{align}
$$\therefore \|u\|_{L^p(U)} \le (\text{diam}\,\Omega)\,\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(U)}$$

$\stackrel{(1)}{=}$ is a result of $u\in W^{1,p}_0(U)$; $\stackrel{(2)}{\le}$ is a result Hölder's inequality; $\stackrel{(3)}{\le}$ is a result of Fubini's theorem; $\stackrel{(4)}{=}$ is a result of the definition of $p'$. Here, $C= \text{diam}\,\Omega$ so it only depends on $U$ but not on $p$ at all.

Is $C$ suppose to have some $p$-dependence that I happened to miss in the proof?

Comment: Looks good to me. In the very last line you write $=$, which should be an inequality.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out; I've edited it.

Comment: I think you must make some assumption about $\Omega$ to go from line 5 to line 6. Since $U\subset \Omega$ and not the other way around, I don't see why $b_1-a_1 \leqslant \mathrm{diam}\, \Omega$. However, I think you can choose $\Omega$ so that $b_1-a_1= \mathrm{diam}\, \Omega$ (after possibly rotating $\Omega$)

Comment: Otherwise I don't see any issue with your proof (though you might want to mention that you are extending $u$ by zero to make sense of integrating over $\Omega$ :)).

Comment: You have to remember that such a $C$ is not unique. I'm certain that the optimal constant must depend on $p$, so all you have done is found a sub-optimal constant which doesn't depend on $p$.

Comment: I think you're right; the slew of inequalities has caused the optimum $C$ to be lost within, causing the $p$-dependence to be buried together with it as well. Thank you for your help.